# Best way to save p12 content and passwords for APNS

Tags: passwords, apple-push-notifications

My APNS server needs to manage multiple p12 certificates/passwords to send notifications.

I'm using a Mysql DB to store p12 binary data and passwords.
The password is currently plain text...and it is a security issue...

What is the best solution to store this password to be able to use it with a "decoded version" when trying to send the notification

Answer (score 1):

2-way encryption is always tricky and there's always a trade-off at some point. I think that a reasonable solution might be to:

- Store the passwords using a well-known encryption algorithm. **DO NOT** invent your own.
- Store the decryption key in a file on your server. It does not have to be the same server where the database storing the passwords is located. Do **not** store the key in PHP. Of course, you must take the utmost precaution to protect the decryption file.

A few options / alternatives :

- You could take this one step further and change the certificate and
  all the encrypted keys in the DB every few hours. If someone is
  trying to brute-force, this might buy you time before they realize
  what you're doing
- Use multiple decryption keys stored on different machines. If one machine is compromised and the DB stolen, without all the decryption keys, the db is worthless. Of course, if all your machines are compromised, you've got bigger problems.